# Norm and determinant of matrices

Tags: matrices, determinant, normed-spaces

I am working on a problem says that if $A$ and $B$ are $n×n$ matrices such that $‖A-B‖≤cε^n$ and $0<ε<1$ , then $$|\det(A)-\det(B)|≤c'ε^n.$$

I assume $\det(A)≠0$ and $\det(B)≠0$, hence $A$ and $B$ are invertible. I use the formula $$A^{-1}=\frac{\mathrm{adj}(A)}{\det(A)}$$ so that $$|\det(A)|=\frac{\lVert \mathrm{adj}(A)\rVert}{\lVert A^{-1}\rVert}.$$ Similarly for $B$ and since these matrices are square then they have the same norms for their adjoints, 
so $$|\det(A)|-|\det(B) |≤\frac{\lVert A\rVert}{\lVert A^{-1}\rVert }-\frac{\lVert B \rVert}{\lVert B^{-1} \rVert }.$$

We can assume there exists $m$ such that $‖A^{-1} ‖^{-1}≤m$ and $‖B^{-1} ‖^{-1}≥m$, hence,
$$|\det(A)|-|\det(B) |≤m(  ‖A‖-  ‖B‖)≤m(  ‖A-  B‖)≤m( cε^n).$$

Similarly, $$|\det⁡(B)|-|\det⁡(A) |≤m'( cε^n).$$

But if this is basically correct I get

$$||\det⁡(A)-\det⁡(B) ||≤c'ε^n$$

My question is, is my attempt correct? how can I reach the final result?

Comment: You need $(\| A^{-1} \|)^{-1} \le m$ and $(\| B^{-1} \|)^{-1} \ge m$. Be careful with the signs.

Comment: yes you are right, I will edit them, thank you

Comment: 1) What is c' and what can it depend on? 2) How did you get that $\|\mathrm{adj}\|=\|A\|$? That is not true. 3) What norm is $\|\cdot\|$?

Comment: $c ́$ is a constant. $‖.‖$ is a matrix norm $‖A‖=sup⁡{‖Ax‖,‖x‖=1}$ and I know that if $A$ is square then $‖A‖^{2}$=$‖A^{T}‖^{2}$ where here the norm is the largest eigenvalue of $A^{T}A$

Comment: OK, so from what you wrote, it seems that $\|\cdot\|$ is supposed to be the spectral norm. I still did not specify on what is $c'$ is supposed to *do* or *do not* depend on! Recall what $\mathrm{adj}$ is and note that it is not the transpose of the matrix! Also have a look, e.g., on [this presentation](http://www4.ncsu.edu/~ipsen/ps/slides_hh08.pdf) to give you some hints on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: oh yes, and thank you for the presentation, I will look at it..